# How can I re-run scriptlet?

Tags: jsp, authentication, scriptlet

I tried to pass `param` variable to a.jsp from start.jsp, using `forward`.  Then a.jsp process the parameters and go back to start.jsp by `form action`. So it's like a run loop.
But a.jsp seems not rerun processing scriptlet.

start.jsp

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${id eq 'id'}">
        <c:if test="${pw eq 'pwd'}">
            <jsp:forward page="welcome.jsp"/>
        </c:if>
        <jsp:forward page="a.jsp">
            <jsp:param name="fail" value="password"/>
        </jsp:forward>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <jsp:forward page="a.jsp">
            <jsp:param name="fail" value="id"/>
        </jsp:forward>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

a.jsp

```
 <body>
    <%
    String failcode = request.getParameter("fail");
    if(failcode == null){
        out.println("<script>alert('get started');</script>");
    }
    if(failcode == "password"){
        out.println("<script>alert('password incorrect!');</script>");
    }
    if(failcode == "id"){
        out.println("<script>alert('id failure!');</script>");
    }
    %>
    <form action="start.jsp" method="post">
         .....
    </form>
 <body>
```

I thought a.jsp supposed to run `<script>` as the start.jsp give them different failcode. What has been wrong in my code? Thank you for your patient reading this.

Comment: I also tried `<% response.sendRedirect("start.jsp?fail=id"); %>`. It can transfer the parameter but still can't retrive the data...

Comment: Thank god, I did not get unvoted. It's just a problem of light knowledge of java. Using `string.equals("text")` will work fine.